# How to combine javascript into html / ASP.Net in visual web developer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

I want to create scripts, and then call them from the html code or the ASP.Net codebehind. How do I do that?

This is probably very simple, but Googling hasn't helped.

For example: I want an `ImageButton` to have an `onmouseover="this.src='...'"`. But I want the script to be separate instead of inline.

Comment: Show some code, hard to tell what you're asking

Comment: Are you asking how to include JavaScript files in HTML?

Comment: @TylerCrompton I guess so. I didn't think of it as a separate file, but I guess that's what has to be done. (I have no experience with js yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especial for this part of your code

```
onmouseover="this.src='...'"
```

you make a function as

```
<script>
  function cOnMouseOver(me)
  {
     me.src='...';
  }
</script>
```

and you call it as : `onmouseover="cOnMouseOver(this);"`

or set it on code behind using the `Attributes` of this control

Comment: Thanks. But can I have that code separate from the html (say, in a separate file)? (What you wrote looks like it goes in the html file. Right?)

Comment: @ispiro The same, you just not use the `<script>`

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageButton btn = .... (from designer)
btn.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "return false;";
```

Replace the string with your generated script. As to @ispiro's comment, you can replace that statement with any legitimate javascript, even a function defined in an external .js file.

Comment: Thanks. That looks helpful. But what I really want is to create something analogous to a C# "method" and call it by name.

Comment: Do You want the button to execute a server side method when it's clicked or another JavaScript method on the client?